# What is the phonetic realization of /ɣ/ and /x/ in Georgian? are they velar? or are they actually uvular?

Tags: phonology, phonetics, pronunciation, georgian

I'm confused as to which symbol should I be using when transcribing Georgian with IPA.

as native speaker of Georgian myself, I feel my /ɣ/ and /x/ sound more like uvular than velar.

I could be wrong tho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This article](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/A7DCF9606BA856FCA5CC25918ADB37EF/S0025100306002659a.pdf/standard-georgian.pdf) on Georgian phonetics suggests that there is no definite answer, because the phonetic realization varies contextually including according to speaker. Listening to two speakers of Georgian pronouncing [the letter ღ=γ](https://forvo.com/word/%E1%83%A6/), the male speaker uses a uvular and the female uses a posterior velar. Also compare [ხ=x](https://forvo.com/languages/ka/) where the same female speaker uses a posterior velar. Most sources seem to classify it as velar, but there is no detailed experimental study that verifies that claim.